# Ansible: ensure directory ownership / permissions across all servers

Tags: ansible

Given a bunch of servers, A..Z, what's the best way of ensuring that all `/dir/path` directories on these servers (where these directories exist) are set to a certain owner, group and mode?

I can see how to do it for a specific role, e.g.

```
- name: Add apache vhosts configuration.
  template:
    src: "vhosts.conf.j2"
    dest: "{{ apache_conf_path }}/{{ apache_vhosts_filename }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  notify: restart apache
  when: apache_create_vhosts
```

but how do you do it across a whole range of servers?

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. But I guess [file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/file_module.html) module with `recurse: yes` is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/file_module.html

```
- name: Change ownership of the folder
  file:
    state   : directory
    recurse : yes
    path    : "{{ folder }}"
    mode    : "{{ desired_mode }}"
```

Execute the task on all the systems you want changed.
Obviously, run it as the necessary user; if that's root, make sure you specify owner and group if needed.

Forgive me if this seems a bit basic, but sometimes it's nice to have the obvious reiterated - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html

To run against a list of servers, put them in a group in your inventory file and call the task on that group as hosts.

Hosts file example:

```
[targetServers]
host1
host2
# etc
```

then in your main.yml

```
- name: do the thing
  hosts: targetServers
  # etc
```

then `ansible-playbook -i hosts -v main.yml` oe some such.